# Issue Injecting Service into App

Tags: angularjs

Currently what I have is an app.services module that I inject into my app like so:

```
angular.module('app.services', []); // services/app.services.js
angular.module('App', ['app.services']); // app.js
```

This works perfectly well until I tried to inject my service directly to my app to save space (lots of other dependencies are injected). So I changed to:

```
angular.module('App') // services/myService.js
.factory('MyService', [function() { // do stuff
```

This causes an Error: $injector:nomod Module Unavailable. I couldn't figure out why this was causing an issue and the research I did on the subject didn't answer my specific question.

Answer (score 0):

So my issue was that 'App' was unavailable when I tried to inject my service. The problem was the order in which I was loading my scripts to the page. Originally I had it set up like:

```
<script src="services/myService.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
// changed to
<script src="app.js"></script> // module 'App' loads
<script src="services/myService.js"></script> // 'MyService' is injected into 'App'
```

I learned this the hard way before when working with controllers and making sure to inject the main controller first then my sub controllers on the same module (which are in different files/directories) are injected. The main reason I did it this way is because I didn't care for having a script that only contains the module definition (which from my research is the correct way to do this).

Hope that helps someone.